# Decompress Dovecot email with LZ4

Tags: dovecot

I've decrypted an email from Dovecot's `Maildir` folder but I can't decompress it properly. Judging by first few bytes, it is compressed using LZ4:

```
00000000  44 6f 76 65 63 6f 74 2d  4c 5a 34 0d 2a 9b c5 00  |Dovecot-LZ4.*...|
00000010  01 00 00 00 00 41 a2 ff  e4 52 65 74 75 72 6e 2d  |.....A...Return-|
```

I've tried `lz4cat` and `dd if=file bs=1 skip=n` with no luck. I can see parts of the message intermingled with garbage (compression data - I presume).

How to properly decompress such message?

Answer (score 1):

With help of `#dovecot` IRC channel dweller `cmouse`, there's the command:

```
doveadm fs get compress lz4:1:posix:prefix=/ message-filename
```

Or with LZ4 decryption as well:

```
doveadm fs get compress lz4:1:crypt:private_key_path=/mail_crypt/ecprivkey.pem:posix:prefix=/ message-filename
```

using 0 for compression level doesn't work anymore. see https://github.com/dovecot/core/commit/9b420dde6e3df30fbadd55e4e8524c809437ee03